# Accord en présence de « chacun » : ils feront chacun son (ou leur) devoir ?

Tags: grammaire, accord

Ceci est issu de la page 56 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker.

> **With *chacun***
>
> If a plural subject is modified by *chacun*, the possessive adjective agrees with the subject. ...
>
> - Nous avons apporté chacun nos provisions.
> - Ils feront chacun son (leur) devoir.
> - Ils sont partis chacun de son (leur) côté.
>
> The third person can be singular or plural.

Est-il vrai que *The third person can be singular or plural* ? Je ne sais quoi penser. Pourquoi ? Par exemple, il y a plus de 10 pages de résultats pour [chacun sa pudeur](http://www.google.at/search?q=%22chacun+sa+pudeur%22), mais il n'y a qu'une pour [chacun leur pudeur](http://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%22chacun+leur+pudeur%22). J'ai essayé [un Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chacun+sa+tenue%2Cchacun+leur+tenue&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3), mais avec le nom féminin « tenue » qui ne paraît pas fonctionner.

Answer (score 1):

Dans « Ils sont partis chacun de son/leur côté », soit le déterminatif s'accorde avec le pronom *ils*, soit il s'accorde avec la valeur sémantique de *chacun*. Dans « Chacun sa pudeur », il n'est pas question de s'accorder avec un *ils* qui n'est pas là.

S'il vous semble étrange d'utiliser *leur* ainsi, considérez qu'en anglais, un tel *their* est obligatoire : on peut dire soit "They each ate their own sandwiches", soit "They each ate their own sandwich", mais on ne dira jamais *"They each ate his/her own sandwich."

Answer (score -1):

La phrase "Chacun sa pudeur" peut être comprise comme "Chacun a sa pudeur". Le sujet ici est "chacun" (donc singulier). Ainsi, "Chacun leur pudeur" n'est pas grammaticalement correcte à mon avis.

Alors que "Ils feront chacun son devoir" a pour sujet "ils" (pluriel), et signifie que toutes les personnes font tous un même devoir, qui appartient à une autre personne.

Quant à "Ils feront chacun leur devoir" signifie que chaque personne fera son propre devoir.

Comment: Je comprends plutôt « Chacun sa pudeur » comme « À chacun sa pudeur » : l’accent n’est pas sur le fait que  tout le monde a de la pudeur, il est sur le fait que la pudeur de chaque personne est différente. De plus, si sans contexte « *<strike>Chacun leur pudeur</strike> » n’est pas correct, « Ils avaient chacun leur pudeur », lui, l’est tout à fait.