# Accorder « elles sont chacune »

Tags: accord, pluriel

Paraphrasant

> Chacune de ces propriétés est définie par une phrase.

.. la locution suivante sonne correct à mes oreilles, mais tous ses accords me paraissent faux :

> Ces propriétés sont chacune défin**ie** par une phrase.
>   Ces propriétés sont chacune défin**ies** par une phrase.

Le premier est-il le bon ?
Cette construction est-elle tout simplement impossible ?

Comment: @jlliagre: *correcte* était correct, il me semble. Pourquoi modifier ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez « Sonner correct » est un anglicisme qui ne pose pas de problème de compréhension. En français plus idiomatique, on dirait « sonner juste ». Sonner est ici suivi d'un adjectif qui a, il me semble, une valeur adverbiale. J'imagine mal « La locution suivante sonne fausse à mes oreilles ». Voir aussi le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sonner) *Le clocheton (...) domine un toit sans couleur à force d'ensoleillement, avec les tuiles (...) qui sonnent **sec** sous le bec des pigeons blancs (Morand,Homme pressé, 1941, p. 33).* (et pas « les tuiles qui sonnent sèches ».)

Comment: D'accord pour l'anglicisme. En français, il  y a aussi "sonne correctement".

Comment: @jcm69 "sonne correctement" était mon premier choix, et puis finalement je trouvais ça pas terrible. L'oreille est bizarrement faite :P

Comment: @jcm69 & Stéphane : https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/adjectives-as-adverbs/

Comment: I would have supported « *Ces propriétés sont **chacunes** définies par une phrase* » but of course I refrained to do it given the unfortunate fact *chacun[e]* doesn't admit a plural form unlike in Spanish: *Estas propiedades son cada unas definidas por una frase*.

Comment: @jlliagre Ay! Unfortunately this looks very bad indeed ^ ^ Although it could definitely make sense. French is weird.

Comment: @jlliagre: J'avais un doute et maintenant il me semble que t'as raison. Une phrase sonne faux ou juste. Mon moral en prend un coup. Je ne sais plus distinguer les anglicismes.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Aah, y'a pas de mal. C'est légitime. [Languages fuse, split and merge again continuously](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPVtAlQot9g), right? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a difficult question and opinions are mixed, as far as I can tell. I would lean towards the singular, but several decent resources recommend either an option or the plural.

---

#### Try the ear test

First of all, always remember to try your ear with a sentence where the difference is audible. Which is preferable between these?

> Ces pots sont chacun très artisanal selon cet expert.
>
> Ces pots sont chacun très artisanaux selon cet expert.

To my own ear the first is markedly better, but then I'm not a native speaker.

**Hard to find references that perfectly match our examples**

I recognize that an adjective, as in these above sentences, is not quite a past participle, but it's hard to find past participles for which the singular/plural distinction is audible.

In fact, as we look at our various resources, we'll have to extrapolate from other signs of agreement if we want to cobble enough data together, because it seems that agreement on past participles is rarely commented on. Instead, this is the basic question I found discussed in most of the sources:

> Ils ont chacun son préféré.
>   
> <sub>Supports singular agreement as in *définie*.</sub>
>
> Ils ont chacun leur(s) préféré(s).
>   
> <sub>Supports plural agreement as in *définies*. N.B. I'm not concerned about the plural on the noun.</sub>

---

#### A quick eye test as well

The eye isn't quite as reliable, but what do you think of this case, intended to shock one way or the other:

> Les courtisans sont chacun allé au festin.
>
> Les courtisans sont chacun allés au festin.

I side with the plural here. (But a similar disclaimer applies: The logic of the agreement in this sentence is very close but not *exactly* identical to the passive « Elles sont chacune définies par... »)

---

#### Grammar: status as a pronoun

Let's think about the grammar for a second to get some background. In terms of its syntactic role, my instinct suggests that we could analyze *chacun* as either a pronoun or an adverb in this kind of sentence.

The relevance is that if it weren't a pronoun, it couldn't affect agreement so we could rule out the singular.

In English it appears to be an adverb; among various examples I could cite, consider:

> The hikers each eat their sandiwch(es).
>
> <strike>The hikers each eats his sandwich(es).</strike>
>   
> <sub>Ungrammatical and nonsensical.</sub>

However, in French, consensus is that it's a pronoun. Even though it appears in the sentence in a slot normally filled by adverbs, there are other clearly pronominal phrases that can go there too (e.g. « Ils sont tous les deux français. »).

One very good reason to analyze it as a pronoun is that adverbs are invariable, but *chacun* alternates with *chacune*.

It's worth noting that another, unambiguously pronominal usage exists in French:

> Chacun est artisanal.

I bring this example up because most of the resources first deal with this case, which we have to read past for our own purposes.

Since it is a pronoun, the problem becomes tougher. Then we have two noun phrases: *Ces propriétés* and *chacune*. Which one will govern the agreement of *définie(s)* ?

On the one hand, the plural *propriétés* clearly governs the finite verb *sont*. But on the other hand, those two are adjacent whereas *chacune* then comes between them and *définie(s)*, so could it "seize the reins"?

Or could the speaker maybe choose who gets the reins depending on their intended meaning? (I'll call this varying them based on the "semantic value".)

The problem is that one grammatical reading or the other doesn't seem inevitable to me. That's what we're going to try and guess from our resources.

---

#### Credible authorities: no direct mention of this issue

Okay, on to various resources.

**French Stack Exchange**

[Here's another question on this site](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8639/accord-en-pr%C3%A9sence-de-chacun-ils-feront-chacun-son-ou-leur-devoir) about this. Unfortunately, it's inconclusive. The answer with one upvote at time of writing suggests that it's the semantic value that determines it.

Specifically, the author says it depends on whether the subject possesses singularly, or all together as one. For our case, then, we'd have to ask if these properties were defined singularly, or all together.

To be honest, I don't think this is a very compelling analysis. The presence of *chacun* already insists on the individuality, so why would the "all together" sense enter into it?

**Académie française**

Here's a [brief article](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/chaque-chacun) I found on "chaque/chacun". Unfortunately, their example sentences raise different issues that are too far removed from our examples to be of any use.

**Office québécois de la langue française**

Third, [this article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1717) on the OQLF. Unfortunately, it's not directly useful to us either, though it has good notes on conjugation in the presence of *chacun*.

**Le Bon Usage**

... To be consulted someday when I own a copy. :s

---

#### Internet grammar websites

Falling back on Google, here are a few resources I found by searching "chacun accord".

**logilangue.com**

The first reference is [this article](http://www.logilangue.com/public/Site/clicGrammaire/AccordApresChacun.php):

> Quand le mot CHACUN renvoie à un sujet pluriel et qu'il est suivi d'un complément du verbe, on utilise les formes NOTRE, VOTRE ou LEUR pour le singulier et les formes NOS, VOS, LEURS pour le pluriel.
>
> Nous faisons chacun notre lit.
>
> Ils nettoient chacun leur chambre.

The author then states this caveat for variation on the semantic basis of whether the complement has a "personal" link with the subject:

> Quand le complément du verbe a un lien peu personnel avec le sujet, on peut employer SON, SA, ou SES ou bien les formes précédentes. - Cependant, les tournures qui sont en rapport avec le sujet du verbe semblent plus logiques.
>
> Nous irons chacun de son côté / chacun de notre côté.

So this author thinks *chacun* only takes over with singular agreement if the element being agreed is not personally related to the subject of the verb. I don't see a great deal of sense in this.

**Bréviaire d'orthographe française**

[This article](http://mapage.noos.fr/mp2/pronoms_et_adjectifs_ind_finis.htm), meanwhile, agrees that the choice is optional, citing again a semantic basis, but this time the one we saw in the other thread here: that it depends on whether you mean they *each* or they *all*:

> Quand « chacun » est placé après un verbe employé à la 3e personne du pluriel, on peut mettre indifféremment l'adjectif possessif au singulier ou au pluriel, selon que la pensée renvoie à un ou plusieurs possesseurs :
>
> - ils vont chacun de son (ou de leur) côté...

As I noted above, I don't find this too plausible given that the use of *chacun* excludes the second case.

The author also mentions the indirect object, where that semantic distinction makes more sense:

> - ils font chacun ce qui lui (ou leur) plaît...
>     
>   <sub>Does each one do what pleases himself, or what pleases everyone?</sub>

However, I think this is far enough from the problem we're trying to solve that it doesn't help us; in *définie(s)*, the relation between the meaning and the agreement isn't nearly so obvious.

**espacefrancais.com**

[This resource](http://www.espacefrancais.com/le-pronom-indefini-chacun-chacune/) has some nice citations under "observations diverses". There's too much here to quote it all, but in summary, the author proposes:

> 1. *chacun* takes *son*, *sa*, *ses* between a verb and a complément direct; between an intransitive verb and a complément circonstanciel; or when the "proposition preceding *chacun* presents a complete meaning".
> 2. *chacun* takes *leur* and *leurs* when *not* between a verb and a complément direct; when between a verb and a complément indirect; or when "the complément that follows *chacun* is indispensable to the meaning of the verb".

If we apply these rules to your sentence, we might say that *chacun* is between the finite verb *sont* and the complément indirect *par une phrase*, hence it would take *leur*; we extrapolate that this means agreement is governed by the plural subject, so we'd pick *définies*.

That said, although there are citations for each of the above cases, it doesn't seem to me to be enough data to generate such oddly specific rules as those.

**parler-francais.eklablog.com**

[This resource](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/chacun-chacune-a4790787) strongly recommends a singular personal pronoun or possessive:

> Lorsque *chacun* renvoie à un nom pluriel, il y a parfois hésitation sur l'accord de la phrase (pronoms personnels et possessifs), sans différence de sens. On parle alors d'accord d'intention. Il semble pourtant préférable d'opter pour le singulier (exigé par l'Académie), plus « logique »

Despite this, though, the author allows for the alternative in every example (perhaps because of this nebulous "intention"):

> → Ces artistes, chacun dans **son** domaine (ou chacun dans **leur** domaine).

But at the end, the author makes this surprising and obviously relevant claim:

> Mais l'accord des adjectifs et participes passés se fait généralement avec le nom pluriel, pas avec *chacun*.
>
> → Des articles, écrits chacun par des spécialistes différents

This is a pretty direct answer to your question. Note, though, that the author qualifies this dictum with "généralement" and doesn't attribute it to the Académie or call it more logical.

**Tally**

Two resources that side either with plural agreement or optional based on meaning, and two that would judge this case to be unambiguously plural.

---

#### Finishing up

This leaves the arguments for the singular something like this:

1. When there's an audible difference, I have a preference for the singular (and so does @jcm69 in the comments).
2. *Chacun* as a pronoun certainly allows us to believe that it could govern what comes after the verb.
3. The resources siding with the plural are not high authorities.

Meanwhile, the arguments for the plural:

1. At least one other person intuits that the plural is correct in another answer. (Also, in the eye test, I had a slight preference for the plural.)
2. All the resources that directly deal with this question or indirectly through possessives lead us to believe the agreement is either optional or plural.
3. The verb is evidently governed by the plural noun phrase, not by *chacun*, as can be seen by its conjugation.

Between these, I would lean towards the singular as having the stronger arguments, but there seems to be a case for the plural.

Comment: "Chacune de ces propriétés est définie par une phrase." est correcte sans hésitation. Tout comme, si ça peut vous aider, "Chacun de ces pots est très artisanal". J'opterais donc pour "Ces pots sont chacun très artisanal".

Comment: @jcm69 Toutefois l'analogie n'est pas parfaite. Notez que quant à « Chacun de ces pots est très artisinal », il n'y a qu'une seule groupe nominale au niveau de la phrase, dont la tête est *chacun*, tandis que l'analyse de « Ces pots sont chacun très artisinal » est plus difficile — et le sujet change décidément entre les deux cas, la conjugaison du verbe étant nettement différente. Je vous invite à faire analyser les deux phrases en suivant [ce lien](http://ow.ly/HWzJ30cxtwj) : ces outils sont loin d'être parfaits mais ils aident à montrer à quel point ces deux phrases sont différentes.

Comment: (Cela dit, votre préférence pour « Ces pots sont chacun très artisanal » en tant m'est plus significatif.)

Comment: Well, thank you for this deep insight into the problem! Ô.Ô I'm sure there is still plenty more to discover about this, and it's crazy how such tiny French rips lead to endless depths. I'll keep up with the idea of **semantic value**, which I like the most (this is what *language* is about, right? ;), so I'll pick the singular which is the most relevant in my context. Anyway, since the case is complicated, I guess I will not get in any trouble with this :P Thank you again!

Comment: @iago-lito Welcome ^_^ Yup, every hard question can open deep channels into the structure of the language... you never know, though, if someone else will find a one-sentence line by the Académie somewhere that deals with this directly, and settles the discussion in two seconds. :p

Comment: @LukeSawczak : j'ai modifié ma réponse. Peut-être aurais-je dû plutôt faire un commentaire ? Je ne sais pas trop...

Comment: @jcm69 J'upvote, je trouve que vous avez amélioré votre réponse. :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak, I did it again : j'ai juste rajouté que la phrase pouvait aussi être mal tournée ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Chacune de ces propriétés est définie par une phrase

est correcte sans hésitation. Tout comme, si ça peut vous aider,

> Chacun de ces pots est très artisanal

J'opterais donc pour

> Ces pots sont chacun très artisanal

Vous pouvez aussi penser à

> Chaque pot est artisanal

*Chaque* est un déterminant singulier. *Chacun* est son équivalent pronominal. Ou encore,

> Ces propriétés sont chacune notre fierté.

et pas

> Ces propriétés sont chacune nos fiertés

Essayons avec un adjectif en *al* et en parlant lentement:

> Ces résultats sont, chacun, idéaux.

ou

> Ces résultats sont, chacun, idéal.

Remarque: dans la 1ère phrase, on n'a pas vraiment besoin du mot *chacun*. On pourrait tout simplement dire *Les résultats sont idéaux*. Donc, si on rajoute *chacun* c'est bien pour marquer l'individualité de chacun de ces résultats.
La grammaire laisse des fois des libertés comme dans *de la confiture de fraise*. Vous pouvez mettre *fraise* au singulier ou au pluriel suivant la sémantique (sémantique n'est peut-être pas le bon mot... la nuance ?) que vous voulez donner à l'expression.
Donc, en rajoutant *chacun*, à *Les résultats sont idéaux*, j'utiliserais *idéal*.
Mais je peux me tromper :)
Et peut-être aussi que la phrase est juste mal tournée ;)

Answer (score 0):

Selon moi la deuxième construction est la plus intuitive :

> Ces propriétés sont chacune définies par une phrase.

En effet, si on se pose la question "qu'est-ce qui est défini ?", ce sont les propriétés. "Chacune" dans ce cas donne une information supplémentaire mais on parle bien de l'ensemble des propriétés.

Comment: Ou bien ... "Qu'est-ce qui est défini ?" → "Chacune de ces propriétés." :)

Answer (score 0):

Je pense qu'il y a simplement lieu de distinguer ce qui est admissible à l'écrit ou à l'oral.

Et je suis affligé de certaines choses que j'ai lues ici.

L'écrit se doit de respecter les règles d'accord en genre et en nombre. Si on n'accepte pas ce principe fondamental en français, tout fout le camp.

À l'oral, comme "Verba volant", l'euphonie est sans doute la meilleure voie.

Bon, allons-y:

1)
"Chacune de ces propriétés est définie par une phrase".
Est correct à l'écrit (et donc a fortiori à l'oral).

2)
"Ces propriétés sont chacune définie par une phrase".
FAUX, en vertu des règles d'accord du participe passé : sont définies.

3)
Ces propriétés sont chacune définies par une phrase.
Est correct, mais à l'écrit, ça peut faire mal ... à l'oeil. Personnellement, j'éviterais.

4)
Ces pots sont chacun très artisanal selon cet expert.
FAUX. Le genre et le nombre de l'attribut sont déterminés par l'antécédent.

5)
Ces pots sont chacun très artisanaux selon cet expert.
CORRECT, mais très laid. Écrivez "Chacun de ces pots..." 
(Notons l'inutilité du "très". Soit ils sont artisanaux soit industriels, ce n'est pas une question de degré mais de nature. Un ou zéro.)

6)
Ils ont chacun son préféré. 
FAUX - la relation du possessif est plus logiquement forte avec le sujet "Ils" qu'avec "chacun", qui est de surcroît dispensable dans la phrase. 
Il suffirait d'ecrire "chacun a son préféré"

7)
Les courtisans sont chacun allé au festin.
FAUX. Le français est déjà assez compliqué comme ça sans qu'on y aille encore introduire des aberrations de cet acabit. "Sont allés", point à la ligne, rendez les copies!
Il suffirait de dire "Ils y sont tous allés". 
Ajouter "ensemble /séparément" s'il fallait préciser, mais en l'occurrence  "chacun" n'ajoute que très peu de nuance.

9)
Ces artistes, chacun dans son domaine (ou chacun dans leur domaine).
Avec une paire de virgule, "Son" est volontairement isolé avec "chacun", donc singulier.

En conclusion, à ceux dont le français n'est pas la langue première, je dirais que lorsque "chacun" se rapporte au sujet,  il est préférable, à l'écrit, pour éviter les situations limite, de le placer avant celui-ci, et non pas après le verbe, et de travailler au singulier.
Et quand le pluriel s'impose, utiliser "tous".

"Chacun" placé après le verbe relève plus de l'oralité me semble-t-il.

Comment: Peut-être seriez-vous bien inspiré de lire ceci https://french.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice. Merci.

Comment: Dommage qu'une information aussi exacte et utile que _«Notons l'inutilité du "très". Soit ils sont artisanaux soit industriels, ce n'est pas une question de degré mais de nature»_ soit enfouie sous tant de commentaires désobligeants. (Et je sais, l'exactitude aussi est une question de nature, j'aurais donc dû être plus exact et formuler _«aussi exacte»_ autrement.)

Comment: A propos de la bonne place de chacun, Les Choses, G. Perec, Habitués à vivre dans des chambres insalubres où ils ne faisaient que dormir, et à passer des journées dans des cafés, il leur fallut longtemps pour s'apercevoir que les fonctions les plus banales de la vie de tous les jours - dormir, manger, lire, bavarder, se laver - exigeaient chacune un espace spécifique, dont l'absence notoire commença dès lors à se faire sentir." Voila qui devrait vous instruire sur l'oralité de la tournure.